# Power demand Curves

Tags: regression, elasticity, curves

Which is the correct way to compute the elasticity in this log log regression?

## Context:

When having an log log regresion:

log(Y) = log(B0) + B1 log(X), being Y= Demand and X Price, B0 intercept and B1 the Price elasticity.

So, when solving the loglog regression, we have:

- B0=100
- B1= -1.1

## Question:

The way to compute constant elasticity (power demand), I see two formulas:

> Demand = intercept * price^-elasticity

[Source1](https://theintactone.com/2020/01/19/estimating-demand-curves-estimating-linear-and-power-demand-curves/)

so with the values: **Demand = 100 * price^(1.1)**

> Demand = (euler_number^intercept) * price^-elasticity
> [Source2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8fqKYRp3_8), min 19:40.

so with the values:  **Demand = exp(100) * price^(1.1)**

The main difference is the intercept, in one way is proposed as "raw" intercept an the other the power of euler_number of the intercept.

As predicted demands are different, Which is the correct one?

Comment: Assuming that demand falls when price rises, you may have an accidental double negative and you want $\propto p^{-1.1}$.  Untangling your regression it would then be $e^{100} p^{-1.1}$ though note that $e^{100}$ is an extremely large number so your $B_0=100$ may also have an error

Comment: @Henry, So in both formulas I may remove the negative sign?

Comment: Assuming that demand falls when price rises, you want to end up with one negative sign to get $\propto p^{-1.1}$.  Where you put that negative sign depends on whether you think the demand elasticity is $1.1$ or $-1.1$

Comment: Ok thanks I didnt realized the sign, I fixed it but I let the question still open as is not solved.